# Dropdown Menu with Submenu with Submenu in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering if there was a code snippet out there (I can't seem to get the ones I've found to work) that allows you to have a list item in a navigation bar that is a dropdown menu. This list item would inside of it have a submenu as one of its list items. The submenu could have another submenu inside of it, this means it would be a nested submenu.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar multi-level">
        <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-menu">
            <a tabindex="0" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blogs<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="0">Action</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                      <a tabindex="0" data-toggle="dropdown">Another action</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                            <li><a tabindex="0">Sub action</a></li>
                            <li><a tabindex="0">Another sub action</a></li>
                            <li><a tabindex="0">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The code I have is here. I've made sure to import the ui.bootstrap as I'm using Angular and have the correct CSS. I have gotten it to work before but I did something idiot and messed it up and forgot to backup to my repo. I thought I could easily do it again but have struggled with it since. Also, my menu is now broken too.

I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: you looking for flyout menus?

Comment: If flyout, then are submenus displayed on click or hover (pure CSS)?